# Eliminar elementos duplicados de un map

Tags: java, map

Por ejemplo tengo esto:

```
{[dificultad, adios]=["baja", "a"], 
 [dificultad, adios]=["baja", "a"], 
 [dificultad, adios]=["alta", "abckdk"]}
```

es decir, un  `Map<List<String>, List<String>>`, lo que quiero hacer y no consigo es que por ejemplo si en el map, si hay claves y valores idénticos que se borren y solo haya un elemento de ellos.

Salida esperada:

```
{[dificultad, adios]=["baja", "a"], [dificultad, adios]=["alta", "abckdk"]}
```

Comment: Si permite claves duplicadas no se suele llamar Map, sino Multimap. Si estás empleando Guava, hay una subclase de Multimap que no permite duplicados clave-valor: SetMultimap. Y lo mismo si estás empleando apache collections. Indica que librería estás usando para conseguir esa estructura.

Comment: ¿No es mejor, al momento de introducir los datos, usar un objeto que no permita duplicados? Así evitarás estar transportando datos para luego desecharlos. ¿Tiene lógica transportar X cantidad de mercancía de un sitio a otro, pagando transporte, peajes, choferes, etc, para luego en el destino desechar parte de esa mercancía? ¿Por qué no la clasificas antes? Piensa la programación siempre basándote en la vida real y evitarás errores de lógica garrafales como este.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A ver si te sirve de ejemplo

No se correponde exactamente con tu problema, pues me faltarían las clases para poder completar tu código, pero es un ejemplo que te puede dar una idea de como enfocarlo

Yo me limito a usar un HashMap de clave valor de dos String, con un valor duplicado, ya que la clave de una HashMap tiene que ser única. En tu caso no usas un simple HashMap clave valor, por eso te permite tener claves duplicadas.

Te pongo el código

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    HashMap datos = new HashMap();

    // Añadimos datos a nuestro hashMap
    datos.put("Nombre","Fernando");
    datos.put("Apellido1","Guiado");
    datos.put("Apellido2","Gutiérrez");
    datos.put("Apellido3","Gutiérrez");

    //Declaramos un iterador para recorrer el contenido del HashMap
    Iterator it = datos.entrySet().iterator();
    
    System.out.println("Mostramos el contenido del HashMap: ");
    while (it.hasNext()) {
        Map.Entry e = (Map.Entry)it.next();
        System.out.println("Clave: " + e.getKey() + "          Valor: " + e.getValue());
    }
    
    int n = 0;
    
    System.out.println("--------------------------------------------------");
    System.out.println("--------------------------------------------------");

    System.out.println("Mostramos el contenido del nuevo HashMap con el valor duplicado eliminado: ");
    //declaramos un primer bucle para recorrer las key del hashmap hm
    for (Object key1:datos.keySet())
    {
        //en un segundo bucle volvemos a recorrer las key sobre el primero
        for (Object key2:datos.keySet()) 
        {
            //si la primera key es distinta a la segunda (No puede haber dos keys iguales)
            if (!key1.toString().equals(key2.toString())) 
            {
                //almacena el contenido en x del a primera key
                Object x = datos.get(key1);
                //almaena el contenido en y de la segunda key
                Object y = datos.get(key2);
                //si los contenidos de x e y son iguales
                if(x.equals(y)) {
                    //eliminas la segunda
                    datos.remove(key2);     
                    Iterator itE = datos.entrySet().iterator();
                    while (itE.hasNext()) {
                        Map.Entry e = (Map.Entry)itE.next();
                        System.out.println("Clave: " + e.getKey() + "          Valor: " + e.getValue());
                    }
                    //damos un valor para el if cualquiera
                    n = 10;
                    //salimos del for
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        //si se cumple el valor que dimos
        if (n == 10){
            //salimos del primer for
            break;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("--------------------------------------------------");
    System.out.println("--------------------------------------------------");
}
```